# How to search for any member of a list of values with sed

Tags: bash, sed, openstreetmap, text-processing, large-files

not sure how to ask the question appropriately, but here's the use case:

- I have an ~18GB XML file (OpenStreetMap); ~250M lines
- The file has ~250 offending entries that are corrupting the dataset
- The entries to be removed are multiline & of form: `<way id="foo">... <\way>`
- I have those ids in a file `bad_ways`

I could write a for loop & cycle through a bunch of `sed` statements like this:

```
sed -i.bu '/<way id="1_bad_way_entry".*/,/<\/way>/d' in.xml
```

but... this requires ~250 cycles through an 18G file & associated disk writes, etc., which right now takes about 18min per cycle (spinning disk... will fix that shortly by switching machines. Update: SSD improves to about 6.5 min per cycle).

Is there any way to ask `sed` to match **any** entry in `bad_ways` and do this in 1 pass?

Or, are there better tools for this than `sed`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: take a look at this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/719118) that generates a file of `sed` patterns (`patterns.sed`) and then uses said pattern file to run the search (`sed -f patterns.sed file`); while the search time will likely increase a bit due to the multiple patterns, I'm thinking this single-pass solution is going to be a lot faster than 250x scans of the 18G XML file eh.

Comment: run a (google) search on `sed patterns from file` and you should pull up quite a few hits, many on stackoverflow (or the sister sites), some a bit easier to understand (like my previous link) while others can get a bit more convoluted, ymmv ...

Comment: Is a solution with `awk` acceptable for you? You might want to add example input/output files (2 patterns, 20 lines input where patterns over more lines occur).

Comment: There are better tools available for working with OSM files. Take a look at osmium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use command substitution to assemble the `sed` script on the run.

(Note: in the following I use `sed`'s `-E` option to save some backslash; if you don't you have to create the `sed` script by including the backslashes as needed.)

For instance, assuming the `bad_ways` file is like this:

```
one
two
three
```

and that the `huge_file` is like this:

```
everything starts with a zero, then one is next, then two, then three, finally four
```

you can accomplish the task with the following command to substitute all patterns listed in `bad_ways` with `XXX`:

```
sed -E 's/'"$(sed -zE 's/\n([^$])/|\1/g' bad_ways)"'/XXX/g' huge_file
```

Then output is

```
everything starts with a zero, then XXX is next, then XXX, then XXX, finally four
```

As you can see, the `sed` script that acts on the `huge_file` is made up by concatenating three strings:

1. `s/` which is single quoted (you should always prefer single quotes, unless you need double quotes, as in 2.)
2. the output of `sed -zE 's/\n([^$])/|\1/g' bad_ways`, which is double quoted to allow command substitution, and which generates `one|two|three`
3. `/XXX/g`.

All this results in the string `s/one|two|three/XXX/g`.

This is not clearly the string that you need for your script, but I hope this answer shows you an example of **how to use command substitution `$(…)` and appropriate quoting with `'` and `"` to craft a command (`sed`, `awk` or whatever) dynamically**.

In hindsight this answer is based on the same "philosophy" as the one in the answer linked off a comment. However I'm not temporary saving the script to a file. This could be of minor importance if the script itself is small (and it is small, based on your description).

Comment: This is an amazing how-to. Many thanks!! (I love the internet!!!)